# How to isolate y after solving differential equation

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}={(1+3x^2)\over (3y^2-6y)}$$
Using separable equations I came up with
$$y^3-3y^2=(x+x^3)+c$$
The only problem is that I do not really have a clue on how to isolate $y$ on the left side. I know this should be basic but the solution is eluding me.  Also can anyone tell me if I am doing this DE correctly?  Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Solve a cubic polynomial $y^3-3y^2+a=0$.

Comment: Can you explain how I would do that? @JackyChong

Comment: I don't think you need to give an explicit solution. You may leave your solution in the above implicit form unless the problem asks you for the explicit solution.

Comment: Otherwise, you will have to look at Cardano's formula which I don't think is a good idea.

Comment: Do you think I am going about this DE correctly?  Or is there an easier way to find the solution? @JackyChong

Comment: What you did is correct.

Comment: Thats what I thought.  but it's an initial value problem also of y(0) = 1.  I should of put that in the original post.  so would c then just be equal to 1 since x = 0? @JackyChong

Comment: No. $c = 1-3 = -2$.

Comment: ohh I get it now.  Thanks a bunch for your help @JackyChong